# Display Image over another image css

Tags: css, image

How to display one image over another image in css file

Comment: Post some code? Screenshot of what you want it to look like? Add some more and maybe you'll get an answer.

Comment: Read this to properly form your question and get a worthwhile response: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers/18616#18616

Comment: i hv this code right now:                                                                                                                                   div.art-header-jpeg
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right:0;
  width: 892px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('http://localhost/adwebservice/images/header.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
Now I want to add another image on this image

Answer (score 5):

With CSS you can specify the [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index) of an element, which will allow you to "stack" elements "on top" of each other when rendering the style to the markup.  For example, you can give two elements the exact same position on the page but different z-index values and they would be stacked, one on top of the other.

This is often used in conjunction with the [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/float) of an element or with [absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position), since traditionally flowing elements generally "push" each other relative to their position rather than absolutely position over each other.  [Example here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index/Stacking_and_float).  [Lots of information here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index).

Answer (score 0):

You should post some more information, but at the very least take a look at the z-index functionality of css [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index). That should help a lot if i understand your question right.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, but the key is using positioning (`position: relative` for example) with z-indexes.

[Here is an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/echopony/Nm2sD/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This is Works on All Major browsers..
Check this out

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.search_customization-icon_icon {
position: relative;
margin-top: -40px;
margin-left: 3px;
width: 162px;
height: 22px;
display: block;
background: url(http://Apparelnbags.com/skins/skin_1/images/anb_icon_sold-with-customization_icon.png) no-repeat center;

}

</style>


</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td style="padding-right:5px;">

<span style="width:190px;height:235px;display: block;">
<a title="Alternative AA04 Ladies Rib Crew" href="http://www.apparelnbags.com/alternative/aa04-53-oz-rib-crew-t-shirt.htm">
<img src="http://images.apparelnbags.com/product/icon/AA04.jpg" style="position:relative;border:0">
<span class="search_customization-icon_icon">
</span>
</a>
</span>

</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```